# auto Refreshing of row count by clicking on dynamic search button in search

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf, jsf-2.2, jdeveloper

In search the search button is dynamically created,we doesn't know the code of the button.our requirement is when we click on the search button we should get the row count. we are getting it .but every time we should refresh the page to get it updated.
if we want to use partial triggers and all stuff we are not able to find the button code.

Comment: kindly post the code for the button component

Comment: <af:query id="qryId1" headerText="Search" disclosed="true" value="{bindings.SearchFunctionalityViewCriteriaQuery.queryDescriptor}"model="#{bindings.SearchFunctionalityViewCriteriaQuery.queryModel}"queryListener="#{bindings.SearchFunctionalityViewCriteriaQuery.processQuery}"
                              queryOperationListener="#{bindings.SearchFunctionalityViewCriteriaQuery.processQueryOperation}" resultComponentId="::resId1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_search.qryId1}" visible="true" clientComponent="false"  />   THIS IS THE CODE OF QUERY FOR DYNAMIC SEARCH BUTTON

Comment: <af:outputText  value="Total no of #{bindings.SearchFunctionalityView1.estimatedRowCount} rows" var="row"
   id="t1" />

Comment: this is the row count tag which we wanted to auto refresh when ever when we click on dynamic search.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you do not have properties exposed for the button as it is a declarative component. 
In such cases you can do partially refresh using your backing bean (programmatically)

I see that your **button** has binding `backing_search.qryId1` , similarly create binding for **outputText**

Now in your listener method in your backing bean, write the code to partially trigger the outputText.

Code for partially triggering,

> ```
>     AdfFacesContext adfFacesContext = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
>     adfFacesContext.addPartialTarget(bindingOfYourOutputText);
> ```